# MS Access split database. Can we still add new tables?

Tags: ms-access, split, ms-access-2013

I have a database in access that has 4 tables and 4 forms that are bounded to those tables. I recently split the database and the tables are now stored in a different file and I have the front end stored on a shared drive(People in the office want to use the database while it is being built, so I had to put it on a shared drive). My questions is, I am planning on adding another table to the database with it's bounded form. How can I link the table and the form when they are going to be in two different files? The other tables and forms work because I used the wizard to split the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking how to do this manually:

1. Open the backend in Access and add the new table. Note that at this time, no user should try to access the backend, be it via your frontend or the Access UI.
2. In the frontend, use the Linked Table wizard to add a link to the new table.

Note: all these steps could be done via VBA as well.